# Node.js express and ejs trying to pass a variable from js file to ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

My folder structure is public-js-color.js     and the ejs file is views-index.ejs

How do I pass a variable from the color.js file into the index.ejs file so I can display it to the user. Please forgive me if this is simple, just learning node and google has been no help.

Comment: Are you trying to have the value compiled into the ejs template on the server, or are you planning to use it only on the client in clientside js?

Answer (score 0):

when you define your express route and call render you want to pass to the view as the second parameter.

```
var variablesToPass = {
  homie: 'who is your homie?'
};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  return res.render('index', variablesToPass);
});
```

You will be able to render homie on your ejs home template by typing <%= homie %>

Also if you would like the variables to be available across your entire application a useful middlware function you could create is.

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.locals.homie = "I'm a homie thats available everywhere";
});
```